# Frequency modulation (FM)

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I'm trying to Frequency modulate an audio signal. I can successfuly FM a sine wave (the carrier) with another sine wave (the modulator) by using the following equation y=cos(Fc + sin(Fm)), however I'm not sure how to go about FMing an audio signal because apparently I can't use the aforementioned formula. My question is: How do I combine the input data with the modulating signal to get an FM signal?

Comment: Belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I haven't been able to get Paul's method to work but I have a working solution for FM synthesis of audio signals. I did a lot of testing in Excel and realized how to do it. Here's the algorithm

```
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)     {
    // increase the frequency with increasing amlitudes (fc + fm)
    if (input[i] < input[i+1])
        out[i] =   cos(acos(input[i]) + A * sin(2 * pi * mf * i));
    else  //decrease the frequency with decreasing amplitudes (fc - fm)
        out[i] =  cos(acos(input[i]) - A *  sin(2 * pi * mf * i));
                }
```

It works well but it does generate some undesirable harmonics (possibly due to rounding errors) so you may have to use some sort of a filter (a moving average might do a good job at reducing those unwanted harmonics). When applied to an audio signal, you will probably have to take the envelope of the audio and multiply it with the modulating signal so as not to apply FM on the quiet portions of the audio etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of FM as just dynamically varying the playback rate, where the variation in playback rate is proportional to your modulating signal. So for normal playback your playback rate is the same as the sample rate, `Fs`. For an FM version of your audio signal you playback rate will be `Fs * (1 + A * f(t))`, where `A` is the modulation amplitude and `f(t)` is the modulating signal. To implement this you will need to maintain a *phase accumulator* with a real and a fractional component, and then update the phase accumulator according to the current (modulated) sample rate. Use the integer part of the phase accumulator to determine the sample index, `n` and use the fractional part to enable you to interpolate, e.g. between samples `n` and `n + 1`.

Not that this is very similar to [wavetable synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavetable_synthesis), except that your waveform table is a sampled sound instead of a periodic waveform. See e.g. [this question on dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/971/how-to-create-a-sine-wave-generator-that-can-smoothly-transition-between-frequen/973#973) for further info.

Comment: Thanks, Paul R. If I understand correctly what you're saying I should do something like

Comment: Thanks, Paul R. If I understand correctly what you're saying I should do something like phi_delta[i] = Fs-Fs*(1+A*f(t)) (i goes from 0 to N) and then add that value to the corresponding phase accumulator (phi_accum[i] += phi_delta[i]). If, say, phi_accum[5] equals 122.223 then I would take 122 as an index into the input data and then simply multiply the input data as (input[122]+input[123]/2)*0.223 Ivan

Comment: @dsp_user: yes - you don't need to actually store phi_accum or phi_delta in arrays of course - just calculate them on the fly - but your description is essentially correct

Comment: Unfortunately that code doesn't seeem to work. I wrote the following piece of code

Comment: Unfortunately that code doesn't seem to work. I wrote the following piece of code `for (i = 0; i < 7999; i++) {
  phi_delta = 8000 - 8000 * (1 + 0.25 * sin(2* pi * mf * i));
  f_phi_accum += phi_delta;
  i_phi_accum = f_phi_accum;
  r_phi_accum = fabs(f_phi_accum - i_phi_accum);
  //i_phi_accum = abs(i_phi_accum);  
  if (i_phi_accum <= 7999)
   output[i] = ((input[i_phi_accum] + input[i_phi_accum + 1])/2) * r_phi_accum;   
   }` I'm getting negative values for phi_accum. And even if I did abs(i_phi_accum), the value of i_phi_accum often exceeds the size of my input array. (out of bounds)

Comment: @hotpaw2 The cos funcion takes an angle as its argument and my input array is all amplitudes so I'm not sure what you mean by replacing cos(t) with f(t). Could you be a bit more specific? thanks

Comment: It looks like there are several problems with the code - I suggest you post it, properly formatted, as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace your carrier equation, cos(t), with an f(t) for your input signal, where t might be scaled by the sample rate for sampled data.  Then modulate dt as before.

Note that, for sampled data and depending on the bandwidth of your input signal, to make this f(t) sound "good" you may need to use a higher order interpolation method combined with a low pass filter (such as a windowed Sinc convolution), rather than just using the nearest sample or a linear interpolation between two samples, which could alias rather badly in the frequency domain.