# frequency modulation (FM) code snippet

Tags: audio, signal-processing, sound-synthesis

I've written the following code for frequency modulation of an audio signal. The audio itself is 1 sec long, sampled at 8000 Hz. I want to apply FM to this audio signal by using a sine wave with a frequency of 50 Hz (expressed as a fraction of the sampling frequency). The modulating signal has a modulation index of 0.25 so as to create only one pair of sidebands.

```
for (i = 0; i < 7999; i++) {
    phi_delta = 8000 - 8000 * (1 + 0.25 * sin(2* pi * mf * i));
    f_phi_accum += phi_delta; //this can have a negative value
    /*keep only the integer part that'll be used as an index into the input array*/
    i_phi_accum = f_phi_accum;   
    /*keep only the fractional part that'll be used to interpolate between samples*/
    r_phi_accum = f_phi_accum - i_phi_accum; 
    //If I'm getting negative values should I convert them to positive
    //r_phi_accum = fabs(f_phi_accum - i_phi_accum);   
    i_phi_accum = abs(i_phi_accum);
    /*since i_phi_accum often exceeds 7999 I have to add this if statement so as to      prevent out of bounds errors   */  
    if (i_phi_accum < 7999)
        output[i] = ((input[i_phi_accum] + input[i_phi_accum + 1])/2) * r_phi_accum;            
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what is your question?

Comment: Well, this code doesn't seem to work and I'm not even sure if it's supposed to work. I asked this question in another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655121/frequency-modulation-fm) and simply tried to implement what I was told there.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of phi_delta is off by a factor of 8000 and an offset - it should be 1 +/- a small value, i.e.

```
phi_delta = 1.0 + 0.25 * sin(2.0 * pi * mf * i));
```

which will result in phi_delta having a range of 0.75 to 1.25.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll give it a try and report the results. Just one more additional question. If I were to use , say, 2 instead of 0.25 for the modulation index then I would get phi_delta in a range of -1 to 3 so it's possible that I get some negative values for phi_accum (if phi_delta is negative at the beginning of the loop). Now how do I handle that situation?

Comment: Actually forget my last comment. I'll give it a try first

Comment: Normally the waveform table would be periodic and you would treat the lookup table indices modulo the size of the table, i.e. the indices should "wrap around". Your sampled audio is probably not periodic but you could still use modulo indexing as a first approximation for now.

Comment: I think it's starting to make sense now. If phi_accum is incremented by the same amount for every iteration (that is no contribution from the modulating signal) we'll have no change in the output but when there are  deviations from 1 in the value of phi_delta we'll get our modulated signal.Of course, it remains to be seen just  how exactly nonperiodicity will afffect the resulting signal. Thanks a lot

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. I tried applying it not only to audio but also to some simple sine waves (consisting of only 1 or 2 pure sines) but the results were rather bad. The FFT is all over the place and while the original signal is mostly preserved this method certainly adds many frequencies that shouldn't be there. Any more ideas?

Comment: In order to debug this try modulating with a slowly varying signal, e.g. 1 Hz sine - you should be able to hear this as playback that speeds up and then slows down. Beyond that it just comes down to good old fashioned debugging,