# Frequency Modulation

Tags: signal-processing

im trying to make frequency modulation. But could anyone explain, what about non-sinusoidal (and maybe non-periodic) carrier? Could we assume some FM( A(t), B(t) ) function, which modulates carrier, given by ABSTRACT(non-sinusoidal) function A(t) with signal, given by abstract function B(t)? could anyone write/explain something about that? what will formula look like in that most common case? I want some kind of recursive formula in terms, like "A(t-1)". Or either some explanation, if that is not possible and why.

[Frequency modulation (FM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655121/frequency-modulation-fm?rq=1)
proposes some kind of "varying playback speed" - but seems it does something wrong.
so i am repeating asking "how?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for a non-sinusoidal but periodic carrier you could easer use a look-up table as suggested by the answer of Paul R, or you could break up the periodic carrier into its Fourier modes, create an individual oscillator for each mode, modulate each one and sum then up.

In the case of a non-periodic signal the phase or frequency is not defined in general. Just think of noise, how should that be modulated? You would need to define what frequency modulation means for arbitrary signals.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a look-up table for your waveform generation then it's pretty easy to modify the standard phase accumulator synthesis method to add an FM input. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655221/253056).

Comment: In simple words, my question was about "A's **pitch** modulation without playback speed modification". now i understand that there is no way to define that **pitch**